# Are there any interfaces in LLVM to compile inline function into internal representation?

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, libclang

I'm developing something based on llvm, and I want to do JIT when running code, in code jited, I use some function in the code not jited(the code of program that generate jit code). but I found it's expensive, costs a lot of time while running the code. Is there some way to compile  the function in the original code to internal representation, and paste it into jited code, something like inline function.
for example:
original code:

```
void f(){
//....
}
```

------------jitted code

```
jitted_function(){
  f();
}
```

what I want is:
--------------------jitted code

```
inline void f(){
//...
}

jitted_function(){
  f();
}
```

the most difficult thing is if I paste the c++ code directly, then I have to parse the functions and classes used by f, and also paste them, I don't want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It's just code :-)

You want code to appear both in the host program and the JITed program - so place it somewhere accessible from both and tweak you build so that it gets included in both places. Is this a problem?

As for the first part of your question, it sounds strange to me that invoking host code from JITed code is "very slow". As long as the host code is also built with optimizations, it should not be significantly slower thank calling a function from the JITed code itself. Perhaps if it's a tiny function which you want to be inlined, there may be a difference. In this case, just get it included in both places.

Comment: because I call original function in a nested loop, function call overhead is huge. that's why i want to make it inline.